# psycopg2 error while writing data from csv file: extra data after last expected column

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert data from a csv file (file.csv) into two columns of the table in Postgres. The data looks like this:

```
#Feature AC;Feature short label
EBI-517771;p.Leu107Phe
EBI-491052;p.Gly23Val
EBI-490120;p.Pro183His
EBI-517851;p.Gly12Val
EBI-492252;p.Lys49Met
EBI-527190;p.Cys360Ser
EBI-537514;p.Cys107Ser
```

The code I am running is as follows:

```
# create table in ebi_mut_db schema
cursor.execute("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ebi_mut_db.mutations_affecting_interactions(
feature_ac TEXT,
feature_short_label TEXT)
""")

with open(file.csv', 'r') as f:
# Notice that we don't need the `csv` module.
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    cursor.copy_from(f, 'ebi_mut_db.mutations_affecting_interactions', sep=';')

conn.commit()
```

The table is created but while writing the data, it is showing below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin<>", line 38, in <module>
    cursor.copy_from(f, 'ebi_mut_db.mutations_affecting_interactions', sep=';')
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY mutations_affecting_interactions, line 23: "EBI-878110;"p.[Ala223Pro;Ala226Pro;Ala234Asp]""
```

There are no extra columns except the two. My understanding is the code is detecting more than 2 columns.

Thanks

Comment: what does the line 23 in your csv look like?

Comment: Line 23 and Line 24 looks like this:                                                              
`EBI-728057;p.Cys34Ser
EBI-878110;"p.[Ala223Pro;Ala226Pro;Ala234Asp]" `
.

Comment: Can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have not told the COPY you are using CSV format, so it is using the default TEXT format.  In that format, quoting does not protect special characters, and since there is more than one `;` there is more than two columns.

If you want the COPY to know that `;` inside quotes do not count as separators, then you have to tell it to use CSV format.  In psycopg2, I think you have to use copy_expert, not copy_from, in order to accomplish this.